# SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider: Access to the database file is not allowed

Tags: ado.net, windows-services, sql-server-ce

I am accessing a SQL Server CE file `dbLogs.sdf` stored on a shared location (with full right to "Everyone") through a C# assembly under a Windows service.

When I debug the service in Visual Studio 2008, it is accessing the .SDF file without any issue but when I actually run the Windows service it throws exception when I try to open the connection. The full detail of the error is as below:

> Error Message: Access to the database file is not allowed. [ File
>   name = \192.168.17.228\shared\dbLogs.sdf]
>
> Source: SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
>
> StackTrace: at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.ProcessResults(Int32
>   hr) at
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open(Boolean
>   silent) at
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open()
>   at LogStat.GetLogDetails(String
>   logType) at LogStat.ProcessLogStats()

I have tried the identity impersonate with username and password authentication in `system.web` section under `app.config` but it didn't work.

But when I copied the same code in a console application and it worked without any issue.

Do I need to provide authentication in window service in some other way?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the Windows Servcie under an account, that has access to the share.

Comment: Thanks for reply,

I already tried that for my window service by putting username and password under "Properties-->Log On --> Log on as: --> This Account" and the service code was able to access the database file. 

But the concern is that why it didn't work even the shared folder containing .SDF file has full permission to "Everyone"

Also the identity impersonate didn't work even I have used in many times while working on the files on network. Any idea?

Comment: In general, accessing a sdf file over the network has limited support, and does not work at all in 4.0